# UNION before INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, union, inner-join

Why when I use UNION before INNER JOIN like this

```
    select some_table1.some_column1,
           some_table1.some_column2
    FROM some_table1
    UNION ALL
    select some_table2.some_column1,
           some_table2.some_column2
    FROM some_table2
    INNER JOIN  some_table3
    ON  some_table3.some_column1 = some_table1.some_column1
```

I have an eror: could not  bound multi-part identifer "some_table3.some_column1"?
All data types are compatible.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are getting an error because that is not valid SQL Syntax.  `UNION ALL` syntax is:

```
SELECT <column1>
FROM <table1>
UNION ALL
SELECT <column1>
FROM <table2>
```

You cannot reference the columns from either query like you are trying to do. If you want to reference, then you will want to use something like this:

```
select *
from 
(
    select some_table1.some_column1, some_table1.some_column2
    FROM some_table1
    UNION ALL
    select some_table2.some_column1, some_table2.some_column2
    FROM some_table2
) t1
INNER JOIN some_table3
ON  some_table3.some_column1 = t1.some_column1
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to join `some_table1` to `some_table3` when `some_table1` doesn't exist in the second half of the query, only the first.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing you are going for something like this?

```
SELECT
(
       select some_table1.some_column1,
               some_table2.some_column2
        FROM some_table1
        UNION ALL
        select some_table2.some_column1,
               some_table2.some_column2
        FROM some_table2
) sub
        INNER JOIN  some_table3
        ON  some_table3.some_column1 = sub.some_column1
```

Comment: yes,it looks like what I want.As I understand I must group results before using INNER JOIN?